# « Délire » veut dire quoi ?

Tags: vocabulaire

J’ai vu sous une vidéo des commentaires du genre « c’est un délire entre eux » qui répond à une question « pourquoi il la vouvoie [en parlant de ces amis proches]».

Il me semble que cela veut dire « blague » mais tout ce que j’ai pu trouver dans le dictionnaire c’est excitation ou trouble psychiatrique.

Answer (score 4):

Oui c'est bien ça ils "delirent" entre eux c'est a dire qu'il s'agit d'un moyen pour eux de s'amuser mais d'une manière qui n'est pas commode comme ici se vouvoyer entre amis . J'espere que les exemples suivant pourront t'aider:

**Exemple:** disons 4 amis qui décident en même temps de se raser la tête a moitié, si un 5me ami vient il pourra leur dire :

*"Mais c'est quoi votre délire?"*

**Exemple 2:** Emilie est une fille connue dans son école pour toujours s'habiller en jaune fluo , si un nouvel élève au lycée demande a son camarade pourquoi ce dernier pourrait repondre :

*" C'est le délire d'Émilie ça "*

**Exemple 3:** Joseph adore la plongée avec les requins ( ou même le saut en parachute ) , si il est avec une personne qui a cette phobie là elle pourrait lui dire :

*" Ah moi ce n'est pas du tout mon délire de faire ça "*

Autrement dit : Votre façon de s'amuser, prendre du plaisir , ou faire une quelconque activité qui soit un peu hors-norme

Cependant ceci reste a utiliser dans un cadre je pense quand même familier (colloquial conversation).

Comment: On peut aussi qualifier un moment de "Bon délire"

Comment: C'est vrai j'ai omis cette possibilité là trés bonne remarque

Answer (score 2):

Un délire peut parfois faire sourire mais n'a pas nécessairement cela comme objectif. On ne peut donc pas dire que c'est une blague.

Excitation et surtout trouble psychiatrique sont à l'origine du sens qu'il faut comprendre, mais le mot est utilisé par hyperbole et désigne seulement une excentricité, partagée ici entre deux personnes.

Délire peut qualifier une passion ou un comportement jugé excessif et que souvent on n'approuve ou ne comprend pas. On peut aussi dire « c'est mon délire » pour désigner sa propre passion ou comportement qui sort de l'ordinaire.